# How do I join a date-indexed table to show 0 values when an item is absent on a given day?

Tags: sql, join, mariadb

Using MariaDB, I'm trying to summarize a date-indexed table, to show both sums for a given day, and if data is absent a 0. Here's a simplified version of the table I have and the table I want as my output.

Input

```
Date        Customer     Quantity  
1/1/2020    A            4  
1/1/2020    A            2  
1/1/2020    B            3  
1/2/2020    B            3
```

Output

```
Date        Customer     Quantity  
1/1/2020    A            6  
1/1/2020    B            3  
1/2/2020    A            0  
1/2/2020    B            3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cross join the distinct dates and customers available in your table to generate all possible combinations, and then bring in an aggregation query with a `left join`, as follows:

```
select d.date, c.customer, coalesce(t.quantity, 0) quantity
from 
    (select distinct date from mytable) d
    cross join (select distinct customer from mytable) c
    left join (
        select date, customer, sum(quantity) quantity 
        from mytable 
        group by date, customer
    ) t on t.date = d.date and c.customer = t.customer
order by d.date, c.customer
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=afb795a51e9fbf271791ddd3bee290c3)**:

```
date       | customer | quantity
:--------- | :------- | -------:
2020-01-01 | A        |        6
2020-01-01 | B        |        3
2020-01-02 | A        |        0
2020-01-02 | B        |        3
```